# Mono.Cecil something like Type.GetInterfaceMap?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

**System.Reflection.Type** contains [GetInterfaceMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx) which help to determine what method implement some method from interface.

Does **Mono.Cecil** contain something like this?
Or how to implement such behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

No, Cecil does not provide such method, because Cecil gives us just CIL metadata as they are. (There is project Cecil.Rocks, which contains some useful extension methods, but not this one)

In MSIL methods have an attribute 'overrides', which contains references to methods that this method overrides (in Cecil there is indeed a property Overrides in the MethodDefinition class). However, this attribute is used only in some special cases such as explicit interface implementation. Usually this attribute is left empty and which methods are overridden by the method in question is based on conventions. These conventions are described in ECMA CIL standard. In short a method overrides methods that have the same name and the same signature.

The following pieces of code might help you as well as this discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/mono-cecil/browse_thread/thread/b3c04f25c2b5bb4f/c9577543ae8bc40a

```
    public static bool Overrides(this MethodDefinition method, MethodReference overridden)
    {
        Contract.Requires(method != null);
        Contract.Requires(overridden != null);

        bool explicitIfaceImplementation = method.Overrides.Any(overrides => overrides.IsEqual(overridden));
        if (explicitIfaceImplementation)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (IsImplicitInterfaceImplementation(method, overridden))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // new slot method cannot override any base classes' method by convention:
        if (method.IsNewSlot)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // check base-type overrides using Cecil's helper method GetOriginalBaseMethod()
        return method.GetOriginalBaseMethod().IsEqual(overridden);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implicit interface implementations are based only on method's name and signature equivalence.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsImplicitInterfaceImplementation(MethodDefinition method, MethodReference overridden)
    {
        // check that the 'overridden' method is iface method and the iface is implemented by method.DeclaringType
        if (overridden.DeclaringType.SafeResolve().IsInterface == false ||
            method.DeclaringType.Interfaces.None(i => i.IsEqual(overridden.DeclaringType)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // check whether the type contains some other explicit implementation of the method
        if (method.DeclaringType.Methods.SelectMany(m => m.Overrides).Any(m => m.IsEqual(overridden)))
        {
            // explicit implementation -> no implicit implementation possible
            return false;
        }

        // now it is enough to just match the signatures and names:
        return method.Name == overridden.Name && method.SignatureMatches(overridden);
    }

    static bool IsEqual(this MethodReference method1, MethodReference method2)
    {
        return method1.Name == method2.Name &&  method1.DeclaringType.IsEqual(method2.DeclaringType);
    }
    // IsEqual for TypeReference is similar...
```

Comment: Can you please provide the missing `SignatureMatches` method? That's a complex thing because it must regard generic parameters and arguments that can't easily be compared.